# Windows 8.1 Bluetooth LE cannot detect GATT service running in an iPad application

Tags: ios, winapi, windows-8.1, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt

I have an iPad application running a custom GATT service (to simulate peripheral mode). Is it possible to connect to this GATT service from my desktop running Windows 8.1?

After reading this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/jj159880(v=vs.85).aspx, i attempted to pair my iPad with my desktop and used **SetupDixxx** API's with filters like **GUID_BLUETOOTHLE_DEVICE_INTERFACE** from *bthledef.h*. But i cannot find the GATT service using Device Interface GUID values.

Can anyone tell me if its really possible to discover this kind of simulated peripheral modes?

Comment: Does you windows device have BLE capability?   BLE shouldn't need pairing

Comment: yes it has BLE capability, it says Intel Centrino Wireless Bluetooth 4.0